# OpenGL ES: glFrustrum at rendering time

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am working on a camera system in a 3d scene on Android.
So far, I used this initialisation code to:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSurfaceCreated()");

        TextureLibrary.loadTextures(m_context, gl);

        //Set initial perspective and viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); 
        float fov = .01f * (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(45.0 / 2.0));
        float aspectRatio = 1.9541f;
        gl.glFrustumf(-fov, fov, -fov / aspectRatio, fov / aspectRatio, 0.01f, 100.0f);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int) _viewportWidth, (int) _viewportHeight);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

        initialise();
    }
```

But now, I would like to update the frustum in the render method, to perform zooms and/or image distortions. However, it seems like the **the frustum update**.

Here is the render code (trimmed of the some fat, which does not contain any GL State altering code, apart from the usual Push and PopMatrix):

```
private void render(GL10 gl)
    {
      //Frustrum update code
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); 
        float fov = .01f * (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(45.0 / 2.0));
        float aspectRatio = 1.9541f;
        gl.glFrustumf(-fov, fov, -fov / aspectRatio, fov / aspectRatio, 0.01f, 100.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         

       //Render all the things here!

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```

As you can see, the snippet where the frustum is set is almost identical, and the values used are the same. However, when glFrustum is called in the render method, **the program will not show anything being drawn**. I find this strange, since the values used are exactly the same (when forcing the aspect ratio).

The viewport is still set/updated in the OnSurfaceChanged method, which is hit at least once.

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        _viewportWidth = width;
        _viewportHeight = height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); 
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int) _viewportWidth, (int) _viewportHeight);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```

I think this may have something to do with OpenGL States, but I haven't yet found a solution, out of everything I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glFrustum()` concatenates with the current matrix. As you haven't done a `glLoadIdentity()`, this means you're going to be multiplying with the previous frustum.

Comment: Yes! Of course! LoadIdentity() only resets the matrix in the current mode, thus only the model view matrix is set to identity, and not the projection matrix, which is multiplied each frame by a new view frustum. Thank you very much! I feel silly.